# Action executed when iphone is turned off

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have created a game... however when the device is turned off I need the game to pause... is there an action like viewdidload for when the device is turned off? thankyou

Comment: When the device is turned off, all processes are killed. I'm not sure if your app delegate's `applicationWillTerminate:` is run when that happens.

Comment: sorry not "turned off" but "put to sleep" when the top button is pressed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If by "off" you mean "sleep", there are two ways:

Implement these in your app delegate:

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
   // do sleep stuff
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
   // do wake stuff
}
```

Or register for these notifications:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:thingThatCares
                                         selector:@selector(whatToDoOnSleep:)
                                             name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification
                                           object:[UIApplication sharedApplication]];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:thingThatCares
                                         selector:@selector(whatToDoOnWake:)
                                             name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                                           object:[UIApplication sharedApplication]];
```

Comment: What would be the "thingThatCares" and where would I place this code??? I have a pause action.

Comment: Any object that needs to know when these events happen. For example, a view controller that drives the game could register itself as an observer for these in viewDidAppear, and unregister them in viewWillDisappear. The methods indicated by the selectors could then pause and unpause.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidAppear: is a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the app Delegate method:

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
```

to pause your game.